# how do I find the intersection points of two curves?

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

> I need to calculate the area using a double integral (converting to polar system), which are
> bounded by the following curves: $(x^2+y^2)^2=2a^2(x^2-y^2)$ and $x^2+y^2 \ge a^2$.
> So I plotted both of these curves, assuming that a = 1. I converted it to the polar system and found $r=\pm\sqrt{2a^2cos2\theta}$. But I can't find $\theta$ using  algebraic method. On the graph, I see that it can be equal to ${\pi}\over{6}$. Then my solution could be like this(the answer is correct):

$$ S=\iint\limits_{S}  \,dx \,dy=4\int_{0}^{\pi\over6}d\theta\int_{a}^{\sqrt{2a^2cos2\theta}}rdr$$
I tried to find intersection point by doing this: $\sqrt{2a^2(x^2-y^2)}=a^2$. But i think that's wrong.

So basically my question is, how can i find this $\pi\over6$ by calculating it? How do I find this intersection point?

Comment: Try solving the equations simultaneously in polar form (you need the value(s) of $\theta$ anyway)

Comment: @DavidQuinn I don't really understand what you mean. Do i need to solve this in polar form?  $\sqrt{2a^2(x^2-y^2)}=a^2$

Comment: You have $r^2=2a^2\cos2\theta$ and $r^2=a^2$….

Comment: @DavidQuinn and what? i generally cannot understand your answers

Comment: So solve $2a^2\cos2\theta=a^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COMMENT AS A HINT.-Calculation of some points in the figure of circle and lemniscata is easy and you know the polar coordinates, say $r=f_1(\theta)$ and $r=f_2(\theta)$ for each curve. A way you can finish is the following:

►Calculate the angles $\theta$ corresponding to points $A,B,C$ in the attached figure; let these $\alpha,\beta,0$.

►►The shadow area, $A_1$,  is given by $$\frac12\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}(f_1(\theta))^2d\theta-\frac12\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}(f_2(\theta))^2d\theta$$

►►►You can finish multiplying by $4$ the area given by

$$\frac{\pi}{4}+A_1+\frac12\int_{0}^{\alpha}(f_1(\theta))^2d\theta-\frac{\sqrt{-2+\sqrt5}}{2}$$

[image]

Comment: ty for answer, but i still dont understand how can i find coordinates of B (intersection point)

Comment: nvm, i figured it out. i was so dumb